# How to structure URI query for multiple values for same key?

Tags: android, database, rest, uri

I'm trying to structure a URI that accesses my data by id.

Currently my URIs are query based like so:

```
.../content?parentList=15&type=note
```

How could I structure a similar URI so that I could query for notes in multiple lists?

Essentially combining the results of the next two URIs.

```
.../content?parentList=15&type=note
.../content?parentList=16&type=note
```

Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: how do I create such uri?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the current draft of the [URI Template spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-gregorio-uritemplate/) (Section 3.6 on page 7), you could do:

```
.../content?parentList=15,16&type=note
```

Comment: That's great! Now I just need to figure out how I can put in the comma without it being encoded by the builder.

Answer (score 1):

The Query portion of the URI doesn't require each parameter to occur only once.  Just repeat the query:

```
.../content?parentList=15&parentList=16&type=note
```

It is also part of the URI template **internet draft**:

```
{?list+}
```

becomes

```
?list=val1&list=val2&list=val3
```